# How can I creat custom menu with bootstrap

Tags: menus, walker, sub-menu

I'm trying to create bootstrap collapsing navbar for WordPress template. I have to add some HTML properties such as data-toggle.  After researching, I found that must customize the Walker class but `start_lvl` and `start_el` just effecting on sub menu.

Generally, how can I create bootstrap collapsing navbar like
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20collapsible%20navigation,the%20button%3A%20%22thetarget%22.) and the sublist displayed like [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) (drop-down menu in collapsing navbar)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this simple class:

- https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: Thanks but I'm like to code my own Walker class